# Change navbar length in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm just starting to develop web pages with Bootstrap, and I'd like to know if there is a way to change the length of a `navbar`. The default `navbar` is too long for my needs.

Current code:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">OWOM- Venezuela</a>
                <li class="active"><a href>Inicio</a></li>
                <li class><a href>Noticias</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course its possible. What have you done to try and change it?

Comment: I havent found a solution to shorten the navbar because it is too long

Comment: You're going to have to use CSS to shorten the nav bar. Have you tried anything with CSS?

Comment: See these docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/ and search for container fluid. It says in the docs that `.container-fluid` goes full width

Comment: Oohhhh yes, i just got it, thanks... Add the answer to mark positive

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kilmazing i got the answer which is CSS, in the CSS file i just had to define the width

```
.navbar {
    width:70%; //70% was enough for me  
}
```